# Using Fetch as Google on AngularJS

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, fetch-as-google

I am working on an eCommerce site and I have been asked to look at the SEO implications of our product listing page.

I have done all the necessary steps to get the webmaster tools working fine on one of our development servers.

After running Crawl > Fetch as Google, I'm surprised to see that the two rendered responses look absolutely fine, that is they are identical, even though I'm using AngularJS to handle the async loading of our products.

As the two rendered results are the same, can I safely assume that Google has no issues indexing the products?

Comment: Don't rely of fetch as a completely accurate simulation of indexing - only true representation of serp rendering is the `site:example.com/your-url` technique.

Google should index pushState with escape fragment, but this article from prerender.io is essentially my go to reference for AngularJS SEO:

`https://prerender.io/js-seo/angularjs-seo-get-your-site-indexed-and-to-the-top-of-the-search-results/`

Since your question is about `Fetch as Google`, you might want to dig in to the docs to see what it can (and can't) do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be confident in calling that assumption 'safe'. Crawling and Indexing are two different processes for search engines.

Google is capable of fetching and rendering (using their preview-engine) a single-page-application generated web-page. But the technology used for generating the rendered responses isn't the same as that used to extract links from a web-page, place them in a queue and so-on.

All that "Fetch and Render" really tells you is that the content/layout of a web-page given to Googlebot, is the same as that used by a regular web-browser - good for identifying when scripts/styles/images are mistakenly blocked.

Now, if you are using Google's `_escaped_fragment_` [method](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) to generate a static representation of your URLs, then you probably can assume that you've enabled Google to *crawl* and *index* those pages. I would try using a simulated crawling tool like [ScreamingFrog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/10-features/) to test this separately.